# Android Exoplayer AdaptiveTrackSelection need to start video with high quality

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using Exoplayer for streaming HLS video content. By default AdaptiveTrackSelection starts with low quality and as it detects good internet speed it switches to high quality. I want to start player with high quality and then it should change as per internet speed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a modification of the "max initial bitrate". This is a parameter you can pass to the `BandwidthMeter`. The `BandwidthMeter` is what determines your bandwidth and how it will select the track based on that information. If you pass a large number as this parameter, it'll default to forcing a higher bitrate. The default is currently `1_000_000` I think (as `DEFAULT_MAX_INITIAL_BITRATE`) - but look this up to verify.

To pass this in, it'd look like the following:

```
final long defaultMaxInitialBitrate = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
final DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new Builder()
        .setInitialBitrateEstimate(defaultMaxInitialBitrate)
        .build();
final AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
        new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter, ...)
```

Some more sources:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3698

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/676

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. By default it is  DEFAULT_INITIAL_BITRATE_ESTIMATE = 1_000_000.

Comment: In this case, do the stream changes to lower resolution when internet speed goes down? Or the video get freezed for buffering? In my case, video started buffering. What could be the possible issue?

Comment: The default bit rate is only for the first segment of the first instance of this ExoPlayer. It will adaptively stream after that. If you're having issues, try looking at your manifest to ensure it has the correct bitrate mappings.